# Тире в поговорке

Tags: пунктуация

"На безрыбье и рак (—) рыба" — нужно тут тире или нет? По идее, тире тут заменяет "это"...

Answer (score 2):

Да, тире здесь оправдано: оно заменяет первую часть составного именного сказуемого. Ср: На безрыбье и рак есть рыба. Главные члены предложения: рак - подлежащее, (есть)рыба - составное именное сказуемое. Именная часть сказуемого выражена существительным в именительном падеже, связка ЕСТЬ опущена, так как в настоящем времени глагол - связка ЕСТЬ в составном именном сказуемом не употребляется. Вместо неё - тире.

Answer (score 1):

оправдано, не необязательно, если в интонации нет паузы.